# Symfony domcrawler iterating through multiple forms select submit button

Tags: php, symfony, css-selectors, goutte, domcrawler

Using the example table html below I would like help with iterating through each table row, and clicking the display button, for each row with DomCrawler. I tried filtering using many different criteria such as below but couldn't figure it out. The DomCrawler worked fine when there is only one form, but having issues with multiple, per table row. Any help is greatly appreciated :)

```
$crawler->filter('.posting-row .display')
$form = $crawler->selectButton('display')->form();
$submitResult = $client->submit($form);
```

I have the following code-pen here which has the example table html I need to iterate through, https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZmQLEE?editors=1011

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
if($crawler->filter('form')->count()){

$form = $crawler->selectButton('display')->eq(1)->form();
$crawler = $client->submit($form);

}
```

Greetings!

Comment: Thanks, but how does this submit for every form in the table?